# Как сделать sluggable в asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Подскажите как в asp net core сделать `sluggable`. 
 К примеру ввожу я в статье в поле `title` "лорем айпсам долорем сит", и в поле `url` генерировалось "lorem-ipsum-dolorom-sit" (генерирует автоматически на англ символы). И также с англ "Lorem ipsum" на "lorem-ipsum"
 Примерно как в laravel(php)
[клик](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable).
 То есть это для формирования url нужно.
 Есть ли какой nuget-пакет для этого? Или как-то через регулярки это сделать готовое решение.

Comment: Пакетов готовых не видел, да и не особо приветствуется поиск библиотек на so. Реализовать-то можно практически из коробки, что сложного? Самое главное - определиться с правилами конвертации поля Title в латынь.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075828/5045688), [2](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22transliteration%22).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , сделал уже как мне нужно, спасибо. 
Только один момент, где лучше создать этот класс, типо как хелпер который преобразует. Просто создать отдельную папку "Helpers"?
То в Controller как метод отдельный мне кажется не лучший вариант делать.